# Download a file / image with AFNetworking in iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, afnetworking

I thought I had it figured out but I just can't get it to work.
I have a method that is called on every URL in an array.
This method have a URL of a picture that should be downloaded in specific path in a Application Support folder for offline use.
But maybe I'm misinterpreting the methods in the AFNetwork library.
My method looks like this:

```
- (void) downloadImageInBackground:(NSDictionary *)args{

  @autoreleasepool {

    NSString *photourl = [args objectForKey:@"photoUrl"];
    NSString *articleID = [args objectForKey:@"articleID"];
    NSString *guideName = [args objectForKey:@"guideName"];
    NSNumber *totalNumberOfImages = [args objectForKey:@"totalNumberOfImages"];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:photourl]];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    operation.inputStream = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:photourl]];

    [operation setShouldExecuteAsBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        DLog(@"PROBLEMS_AF");
    }];
    DLog(@"URL_PHOTOURL: %@", photourl);
    DLog(@"indexSet: %@", operation.hasAcceptableStatusCode); 
    [operation  response];

    NSData *data = [args objectForKey:@"data"];

    NSString *path;
    path = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Library/Application Support/Guides", NSHomeDirectory()];
    path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:guideName];
    NSString *guidePath = path;
    path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:photourl];

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:guidePath]){
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:path
                                                contents:data
                                              attributes:nil];
    }

    DLog(@"path: %@", path);
    operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:path append:NO];
    [operation start];


    DLog(@"isExecuting: %d",[operation isExecuting]);
    DLog(@"IS_FINISHED: %d",[operation isFinished]);


  }

}
```

PhotoURL is the direct link to the image that I want to download.

Since this method is called for all the images, all logs is called several times, and seems to be correct.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You have a few problems here. so first, why are you using `@autoreleasepool`? i think there is no need for this here. also, are you using ARC? i consider this, for the rest of my answer.

in AFNetworking there is a class called `AFImageRequestOperation` , so this would be a good idea for you to use. first, import it

```
#import "AFImageRequestOperation.h"
```

then you could create an object

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:photourl]];
AFImageRequestOperation *operation;
operation = [AFImageRequestOperation imageRequestOperationWithRequest:request 
    imageProcessingBlock:nil 
    cacheName:nil 
    success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {

    } 
    failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }];
```

now, in the success block, you got the UIImage you need.
there you need to get the documents directory. your code will not work on an ios device.

```
// Get dir
NSString *documentsDirectory = nil;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *pathString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",documentsDirectory, guideName];
```

and then you could use NSDatas `writeToFile`

```
// Save Image
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 90);
[imageData writeToFile:pathString atomically:YES];
```

at last, you need to start the operation

```
[operation start];
```

all together:

```
- (void)downloadImageInBackground:(NSDictionary *)args{

    NSString *guideName = [args objectForKey:@"guideName"];
    NSString *photourl = [args objectForKey:@"photoUrl"];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:photourl]];

    AFImageRequestOperation *operation = [AFImageRequestOperation imageRequestOperationWithRequest:request 
        imageProcessingBlock:nil 
        cacheName:nil 
        success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {

            // Get dir
            NSString *documentsDirectory = nil;
            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *pathString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",documentsDirectory, guideName];

            // Save Image
            NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 90);
            [imageData writeToFile:pathString atomically:YES];

        } 
        failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }];

    [operation start];
}
```

Comment: You pointed me straight. Had some doubts about what I was doing, thank you very much.

Comment: additional: if you have multiple requests at once, consider using an `NSOperationQueue` (all AFRequestOperation Classes are coding compliant) and let the queue handle the operations. this could come in handy and will not fire 100 requests at the same time.

Comment: How many requests can an app usually handle without implementing NSOperationQueue?, it will never be more than 50 requests, is that enough that it's worth implementing?

Comment: yes, if you do these requests simultaneously i would implement it, especially because this are only 3-4 lines of code.

Comment: @Joakim Engstrom Ist not the app that limits the requests, usually it's the internet connection. Often WAN connection can only handle 1 downloads at a time. It's better trying to keep things in order before trouble happens - like choise mentioned with a queue. You can easily limit this queue with setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1

Comment: `AFImageRequestOperation` was __deleted__ from `AFNetworking`. Use `AFHTTPRequestOperation` and set its `responseSerializer` to an `AFImageResponseSerializer`

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is, the operation is not retained. It will be deallocated immediately.

Either make the operation a property of your class or let a operation queue (also a property) handle the request for you (recommended). In the latter case don't call `[operation start]`.
When you use `AFHTTPClient` the operation queue will also be managed for you.

Also you should register a completion callback for the request operation (`setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:failure:`).