# How can i do multiple download from different URL?

Tags: ios, download, nsurlconnection

I have a program that download a video from a url using NSURLConnection, but i'm not able to do multiple download at the same time.
How can i do it?

Comment: Use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13996621/downloading-multiple-files-in-batches-in-ios

Answer (score 1):

AFNetworking is a very popular framework for doing this and I think it will help

check this https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

and this: [Download a file / image with AFNetworking in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11186854/download-a-file-image-with-afnetworking-in-ios)